# How to make .htaccess rewrite for language subdomain versions?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my project requires language versions and for SEO purposes I want not to create $_SESSION for language but to use subdomain name for the language version. Let say my russian version of website looks like:

```
ru.example.com
```

I want when user visits http://ru.example.com .htaccess file to load index file which is located in the root of the website..
But this is not all ! For example if user visits: http://ru.example.com/products/ .htaccess file to load index file which is located in http://example.com/products/

Is it possible this to be done somehow? Basicaly I wish subdomain name ru to be ignored somehow when server loads the file in url..

So far I have this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ru\.example\.com$
```

and I dont know how to complete the rest..

Please help if this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is simply to have all your language subdomains served by the same website. No mod_rewrite required. You can check HTTP_HOST in your php to see which is being accessed. Put them all in `ServerAlias` or just use a generic `ServerAlias *.example.com`.

Make sure to also set `UseCanonicalName off` so any self-referential URLs that Apache generates will use whatever host was visited and not drop your language subdomain. [Reference here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname).

If you can't do that, let us know your hosting setup, and as long as it's on the same server it can probably be done with rewrites.

Comment: #SuperDuperApps Honestly mate I am very far from understanding what you mean :) Server settings are always nightmare for me and very often I rely on my hosting company support.. Please tell me which settings you want me to change in php.ini file so I can set the server the way you propose and I will follow them, thank you for helping me !

Comment: and to clarify I have no access to httpd.conf file on public shared hosting.

Comment: Ok so contact your host and tell them you want the website to serve *.example.com as in anything.example.com will all serve your website. Alternatively tell them you want [list all your language subdomains] to be served by your website. How it is done depends on the hosting provider. Once that's done just set up each language subdomain to point to the same IP address as your website, or your hosting provider may do that part. Once complete, you can tell which subdomain is being visited by checking $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].